# Disabling/Removing caret from chat window

Tags: c++, winapi, controls, richedit

I have setup richedit control as a chat window and I've no idea how to remove the blinking caret from the control, does anyone know how to do that in edit/richedit control?

Comment: Since you say rich edit control, I am assuming you are using Windows controls. Is my assumption correct? If yes, doesn't the cursor disappear once the control looses focus?

Comment: Yes, standard rich edit control 2.0. It does but I need to remove it when the window has keyboard focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this page](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=393789), you need to handle the `EN_SETFOCUS` Windows message and call [`HideCaret()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648403%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  The docs there say that calls to `HideCaret()` are cumulative, so you probably should only call it once (use a `static` variable to remember whether it has been set), or alternatively call `ShowCaret()` in response to `EN_KILLFOCUS`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`HideCaret()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648403%28VS.85%29.aspx).